# X_train, y_train from transformed data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How do i obtain X_train and y_train separately after transforming the data

Code

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 


DATA=pd.read_csv("/storage/emulated/0/Download/iris-write-from-docker.csv")

X = DATA.drop(["class"], axis = 'columns')
y = DATA["class"].values
        
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state = 42)
                                 
pipe=Pipeline(steps=[('clf',StandardScaler())])
dta=pipe.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)

print(dta)

#print(X_train,y_train) from dta
```

I want to obtain transformed `X_train` and `y_train` from `dta`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `fit_transform()` is the transformed version of `X_train`. y_train is not used during the fit_transform() of your pipeline.

Therefore you can simply do as follows to retrieve the transformed `X_train` as `y_train` remains the same:

```
pipe=Pipeline(steps=[('clf',StandardScaler())])
X_train_scaled = pipe.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Comment: Gotcha , but i the case of https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html X_train will be ignored and only y_train will be considered for transformation, am i correct..??

Comment: Also if i include LabelBinarizer() and StandardScaler() into one pipeline then both X_train and y_train should be used during fit_transform right..? what should i do in that case to obtain them separately

Comment: `LabelBinarizer()` cannot be included inside a pipeline as it is processing `y`. `fit_transform` is simply passing `y` through in order to use the final estimator.